# IOS Compare 2 images that are 80% - 90% same?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, duplicates, compare

i want to compare 2 image that are 80% - 90% same means if i take two images i 1st image I'm standing in the middle of the image and in another i standing little bit away from the centre with the same pose then this will not work of me and one image is blur and another is clear then also it will not return true or if the 1 image is little dark another is bright then must return true ...

how to make it run using hashing technic or if any another technic any help will be appreciated a lot ....thank you

one of the technics m using code is as below but its not working of me:

```
-(CGFloat)compareImage:(UIImage *)imgPre capturedImage:(UIImage *)imgCaptured
```

{

```
int colorDiff;
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imgPre.CGImage));
int myWidth = (int )CGImageGetWidth(imgPre.CGImage)/2;
int myHeight =(int )CGImageGetHeight(imgPre.CGImage)/2;
const UInt8 *pixels = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

int bytesPerPixel_ = 4;
int pixelStartIndex = (myWidth + myHeight) * bytesPerPixel_;
UInt8 alphaVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex];
UInt8 redVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 1];
UInt8 greenVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 2];
UInt8 blueVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 3];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(redVal/255.0f) green:(greenVal/255.0f) blue:(blueVal/255.0f) alpha:(alphaVal/255.0f)];
NSLog(@"color of image=%@",color);
NSLog(@"color of R=%hhu/G=%hhu/B=%hhu",redVal,greenVal,blueVal);


CFDataRef pixelDataCaptured = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imgCaptured.CGImage));
int myWidthCaptured = (int )CGImageGetWidth(imgCaptured.CGImage)/2;
int myHeightCaptured =(int )CGImageGetHeight(imgCaptured.CGImage)/2;
const UInt8 *pixelsCaptured = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelDataCaptured);

int pixelStartIndexCaptured = (myWidthCaptured + myHeightCaptured) * bytesPerPixel_;
UInt8 alphaValCaptured = pixelsCaptured[pixelStartIndexCaptured];
UInt8 redValCaptured = pixelsCaptured[pixelStartIndexCaptured + 1];
UInt8 greenValCaptured = pixelsCaptured[pixelStartIndexCaptured + 2];
UInt8 blueValCaptured = pixelsCaptured[pixelStartIndexCaptured + 3];
UIColor *colorCaptured = [UIColor colorWithRed:(redValCaptured/255.0f) green:(greenValCaptured/255.0f) blue:(blueValCaptured/255.0f) alpha:(alphaValCaptured/255.0f)];

NSLog(@"color of captured image=%@",colorCaptured);

NSLog(@"color of captured image R=%hhu/G=%hhu/B=%hhu",redValCaptured,greenValCaptured,blueValCaptured);

colorDiff=sqrt((redVal-249)*(redVal-249)+(greenVal-greenValCaptured)*(greenVal-greenValCaptured)+(blueVal-blueValCaptured)*(blueVal-blueValCaptured));

return colorDiff;
}
```

Comment: unless I'm missing something, you are just checking the first pixel of each image - surely you need to iterate through the whole image?  Even if you did that, if all you're comparing is average color, then you will get a perfect match between a test image and a second image completely filled with the average

Comment: so any other solution for this .... i m using hashing method but not getting how to use it @Russell

Comment: I guess you will have to compare more pixels, and get an average color, so than decide how much dark and light this color can be to return true, and do the math. To check blur, you might have to compare the pixels on the same image, and also apply a calculation to see how much blur is allowed, or how similar pixels are between them.

Comment: @GilBeyruth i m comparing some pixels but this is also using lot of memory for this so it will not work for me

Comment: hey do you know how to use hashing for comparing similar images........@GilBeyruth